# Access to LXD from a snap

Tags: apt, snap, lxd

I am trying to build a snap which accesses the local LXD service. There is a [snap interface for LXD](https://snapcraft.io/docs/lxd-interface), but trying to use this gives me connection errors.

The (very brief) documentation of the interface requires you to set LXD_DIR to `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd`. I tried both that as well as `/var/lib/lxd/`.

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with a apt based installation of LXD 3.0.3. Is it possible, that the snap interface only works for a snap based installation of LXD?
If yes, is there some way  to interface to a apt based LXD from within the snap?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to use the `lxd-support` snap interface, you need to migrate to the LXD snap package.

Note that your snap package needs to manually connect to the `lxd-support` interface.

If you want your snap to access the deb package of LXD, then you need to forgo all protections in snap packages. Use either `classic` or `devmode` confinement.